# admin magento connect access to www. domain.com denied in magento1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, magento-connect-manager

we facing there error
"Access to www.domainname.com was denied
You don't have authorization to view this page.
HTTP ERROR 403"
I have writable permission on directory 755 and file 644 but not work 
kindly have any solution
and we access any file in downloader directory in any custom file to too same error

Comment: did you check our .htaccess file ? if that is being read by server

Comment: yes now facing There was no 404 CMS page configured or found.in magento connect